# What is the polynomial & Initial state for descramble/scramble the data of vehicle ethernet 10Base-t1s transmit & recieve?

Tags: automation, decode, ethernet-phy

I have tried to understand how the 10Base-t1s works in physical layer. I have read the documents & watch the youtube video. But I still cannot find how it descrambled the data to MAC.

[Packet from DSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Kel.png)

[Descrambled Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tssC5.png)

[Video Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMydG.png)

Could any kind-hearted individual provide me with documents or explanations for me to study?
Thank you!